# Bash Script for Secure transfer

Tags: bash, ssh, scp

The idea is simple, I want to be able to execute the `scp` command from my system and move files to another computer and vice versa.

My case has a small problem. In order to connect to the end computer I have to first ssh to a host_b and then ssh to host_c.

Long story short, I have to copy all my files to host_b first and then to host_c

This is the scematic:

```
my_computer -> host_b -> host_c
```

Since, I have to do this in order to run my code manually every time, it's getting kinda frustrating, So I thought that I should make my own script to automate this process.

Here's my code so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

echo
echo "Move files from your computer to HostC!"
echo

printf 'Username for hostB: '
read -r userB
hostb_addr='hostb.com'

printf 'Username for hostC: '
read -r userC
hostc_addr='hostc.com'

printf 'File you want to move: '
read -r filepath

scp_params='-P 8140'

# connect via scp to hostB
spawn scp $scp_params $filepath $hostb_user@$hostb_addr:~/temp_transfer

interact
```

The main idea is to get the files from my computer to a temporary folder to hostB, scp them again to hostC and then delete the files from hostB.

I've started trying to make this work but I'm getting a 'spawn command not found'

NOTE: this is actually the first time i've used bash

Comment: @shellter no you can't because of security... You are supposed to do it the way I told you unless you are hardwired in the company's network. So it's kind of a pickle to work from home

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's already a builtin feature in ssh/scp to do this. You can open a ssh-tunnel from your local position the your hostB, and than to hostC in one command. In scp you can do this with the -o flag.

```
scp -o ProxyCommand="ssh $hostB nc $hostC 22" $path_to_file $hostC:$path_to_file
```